# How to unbind a key from a command in general.el?

Tags: key-bindings, init-file, evil

I am using emacs with evil, and `space` is my leader key, however, `space` is bind to `dired-next-line` in `dired-mode`. So, how can I unbind `space`, so I can still use it as my leader key in `dired-mode`, and how can I achive this in genral.el.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only reason that space won't work as expected in dired is because `evil-integration.el` sets up `dired-mode-map` to override evil keybindings. You can prevent the file from loading, but alternatively, you can bind your space commands in [general-override-mode-map](https://github.com/noctuid/general.el#override-keymaps-and-buffer-local-keybindings). Then you won't need to unbind space for any minor mode even when using `evil-make-overriding-map`. See my [evil guide](https://github.com/noctuid/evil-guide#further-integrating-evil-and-emacs) if you want more information.

Comment: Great answer, great guide. They help me know `evil-mode` much more. BTW, thank you for `general.el`, all my key bindings are defined in general now.

Comment: As the general README says: "When general-override-mode is enabled, keys bound in general-override-mode-map will take precedence over keys bound in any other minor mode keymaps." Since `dired-mode` is a major mode, how can I override `SPC` which is binded to `dired-mode`.

Comment: The same should apply to major modes for evil keybindings (evil overriding maps which are used to elevate dired's keymap have a lower precedence than the evil intercept maps used for `general-override-mode-map`). If you have any problems, please make an issue on the general.el repository (I don't check stack exchange very often).

Answer (score 1):

To unbind `SPC` in `dired-mode`, you can write something like this:

```
(define-key dired-mode-map (kbd "SPC") nil)
```

I don't know general.el but I guess you should be able to do something similar.

Comment: Please mark the answer as being the correct one.

Comment: Sorry, I find out that @noctuid's answer is more comprehensive, and explains some useful detail about how key bindings work. So, I chose his answer as accepted one.